# Ember.js new router navigation error message: Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have been trying the new Router and the new Ember code (Version: v1.0.0-pre.2-366-g4772b18), and I am in a bit of a trouble. I want to do a simple thing: when I click a link, it should navigate away to that state.

But instead I get this error:

> assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.

To trigger the error, click the big red title. The first one on the top - the one that says 'Ember Ready'.

I have no JSFiddle, but you can check the live site here: http://eduardmoldovan.com/ I have basically pushed the same code there.

My code:

```
var Ngin = window.Ngin = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function() {
        "use strict";
        this.set("Router.enableLogging", true);
        this.set("Router.location", "history");
    },
    customEvents: {
        blur: "blur",
        paste: "paste",
        changed: "changed"
    }
});

DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
    article: "article"
});

Ngin.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        namespace: "private-api",
        bulkCommit: true
    })
});

Ngin.Article = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("string"),
    lead: DS.attr("string"),
    url: DS.attr("string"),
    pubdate: DS.attr("date"),
    channel: DS.attr("string")
});

Ngin.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content: [],
    goToArticle: function() {
        "use strict";
        this.get('target').transitionTo("article");
    }
});
Ngin.IndexModel = DS.Model.extend({});

Ngin.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "page"
});

Ngin.Router.map(function(match) {
    "use strict";
    match("/").to("index");
    match("/technical/:url/").to("article");
});

Ngin.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        "use strict";
        var all,
            latestOne,
            latestList;
        latestOne = Ngin.Article.find({
            filter: 'latest-one'
        });
        latestList = Ngin.Article.find({
            filter: 'latest-list'
        });
        controller.set('latestOne', latestOne);
        controller.set('latestList', latestList);
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        "use strict";
        this.render("header", {
            outlet: "header"
        });
        this.render("index", {
            outlet: "content"
        });
        this.render("footer", {
            outlet: "footer"
        });
    }
});


Ngin.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        "use strict";
        console.log('ede');
        return Ngin.Article.find(params.url);
    },
    setupController: function(controller) {
        "use strict";
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        "use strict";
    }
});

$("body div").remove();

Ngin.initialize();
```

And a simple action like this: `{{action goToArticle}}`

I don't really understand who wants to call what. Any idea on this? I have been looking for answers or examples, but haven't been lucky with that.

Comment: What do I have to do to trigger the error?

Comment: You have to click the big red title. the first one on the top, the one that says 'Ember Ready'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `transitionTo` without supplying a model.

Ember is trying to transition to the `article` route. In order to do that, it needs to generate value of `:url` dynamic segment. In order to get that, it passes the model that you pass as the second parameter to `transitionTo` to the route's `serialize` method.

The default `serialize` method tries to fill in the dynamic segment with the `id` property of the model.

Your action is:

```
{{action goToArticle}}
```

It should be:

```
{{action "goToArticle" article}}
```

Then, you need to update your `IndexController` to take the parameter:

```
Ngin.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content: [],
    goToArticle: function(article) {
      this.transitionTo("article", article);
    }
});
```

All of that said, you really should be using a link here, not an action. That would handle everything for you:

```
{{#linkTo "article" article}}{{article.title}}{{/linkTo}}
```

You can learn about [the link helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/) and [the action helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) in the Ember guides.